# Debugging GWT with Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, gwt, visual-studio-code

I'm working on trying to make the switch from Eclipse to VS Code because I've been using VS Code for smaller scripts and things like that and I really enjoy it. At work we build and maintain a web app that was built with GWT, so being able to debug with things like Dev Mode and Super Dev Mode are important to me. I've looked for GWT extensions similar to what's available for Eclipse, but there don't appear to be any. Is there a way to imitate what Dev Mode and Super Dev Mode do in Eclipse, but with VS Code?

Comment: have you tried: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code

Comment: do you use the gwt maven plugin from Thomas Broyer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Super Dev Mode running, below is an example of a VS Code debug launch configuration:

```
"launch": {
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:8888",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "http://localhost:9876/sourcemaps/MY_MODULE/com/path/to/class/*": "${workspaceFolder:MY_MODULE}/src/com/path/to/class/*",
        "http://localhost:9876/sourcemaps/MY_MODULE/com/some/other/class/*": "${workspaceFolder:OTHER_MODULE}/src/com/some/other/class/*",
    },
    "smartStep": true,
    "skipFiles": ["MY_MODULE-*.js"], // I choose to skip this file because it is very large and not handled well by VS Code
    "trace": "verbose",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder:MY_MODULE}/war" // path to where your war is built out to
  }
],
```

A good way to arrive at what Source Map Path overrides to use is to browse the actual sourcemaps.  With Super Dev Mode running, access http://localhost:9876/sourcemaps and match these paths to your local directory.  In my example above we have a multi-project workspace with some projects living in a different path but still under the same "MY_MODULE".  So the above example is within a Workspace configuration file.  If you're not using a workspace, then you'll need to remove ${workspaceFolder:X} or replace with a more suitable variable.